# Iphone: OpenGL ES 2.0 - Color picking method reacts slow the 1st time

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es-2.0

My app deals with OpenGL ES 2.0 ; and i use color picking to identify which object has been touched during the tap.

Every time i tap for the 1st time on an object, it is very slow to react but the second time it is very quick to react. For example, tapping 1st time on a specific screen takes 0.45 seconds , the 2nd time it takes about 0.01 seconds.

While debugging i have identified that the troublesome code is the following one:

```
    [effectTmp prepareToDraw];
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MaterialVertexData3D), &vertexDataMaterial[0].vertex);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MaterialVertexData3D), &vertexDataMaterial[0].normal);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, [drawObjectTmp getSizeFromVertexIndicesArray]);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
```

I've read the off-screen pre-loading of the object would help. From the log, i can read that the pre-loading of those objects takes as much as the 1st time above, i.e 0.45 secs. However, when i tap the first time , it also takes 0.45secs. After a prewarning, the expectations would be that it takes as much as the second time (0.01sec).

Another thing that puzzles me : the 1st slow call is a color picking call ; meaning each object has displayed off-screen with a particular color that helps in identifying them. It also means that these objects are already visible on the screen (with their textures), so i would have assumed that the vertices would be pre-loaded; and that such issue would be noticable at the loading of the objects when they are displayed on the screen, not during color picking...

Have any of you met such behaviour ? 
How did/would you address the problem ?

cheers,
-Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

the issue wasn't coming from the color picking algorithm even though the timer function indicated so.

While implementing a fade-out / fade-in screen feature, i have realized the color picking method was fast as the screen was fading out fast; however the fade-in of the next screen was slow. It comes from the fact that textures , even though loaded (here with Glktextureloader), will actually take some time at the first render.

A workaround is to display these textured objects off-screen at the initialization phase of the app.